# .map() method print "," between items

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Using `.map()` method create "," separator between my returned items.

I am trying to return a piece of HTML code with inserted data using back quotes and ${} in a drag & drop list project where everything is created from the interface instances. However, I am experiencing a bug? Not sure I should call this a bug.

Is there a way to remove or skip separators between iterations?

This is my main.js where I call the createListInstance function which contains the function from the module that will create the instance, then add functionality to it.

```js
...
createListInstace(
    { title: document.querySelector('.modal-input').value, items: ['item1', 'item2'] }
...
);
```

So I am passing the above dummy data into this function.

```js
function createListInstace(data) {
    // Create list
    interfaces.listInstance(data);
    ...
}
```

Which will land here:

```js
export const listInstance = (data) => {
 ...
 ${data.items.map(item => {
        return (
            `<div class="list_el_wrapper draggable_item" draggable="true">
                <li class="list_el" >${item}</li>
                <button id="del-list_el" value=${item} type="submit">X</button>
            </div>`
        )
  })}
 ...
}
```

I am not mutating anything from the first step to the last.
And this is what I get:

[image: Printing "," between items]

From this object:

[image: Origin object to use .map() method on]

I have tried to `.join(" ")`, even `.split(" ")` back the array but no result :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: there must be typo

Comment: Have you tried `${data.items.map(/*your logic*/).join("")}`?

Comment: @HassanImam I knew I encountered this before... that's why I was trying to join(" ") but did not know where to use it. I used it on the input, not on the end of my logic. Solved, thanks!